# Extend imported component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using single file components and I'd like to know is there any way to extend imported component

For example I have Products.vue and Filter.vue component. Products.vue component contains string with table name it gets data from. Filter.vue to work should know table name it filters. Normaly I should pass that data with props from Products.vue to Filter.vue. But the problem is that there is multiple filters that becomes repetitive and I'd like to avoid it.
Will be good if there is some construction for extending imported component like:

Products.vue:

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
import Filter from './Filter.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    // something like
    'extendedFilter': Filter.extend({ data() { return { table: this.table_name } } })
  },
  data() {
    return {
      table_name: 'test_table'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```